# Why is changing the sharepoint configuration database from the registry unsupported?

Tags: timer-service, psconfig, registry

I have a sharepoint 2010 server pointed to an old DNS entry we used for our SQL configuration database.

It turns out that I do not want to use that DNS entry, but a different one in my connection string (the original entry should have never been used).

I have seen in a lot of places that the connection string to the sharepoint config DB is stored in the registry, but everywhere I have looked it says that if I need to change the connection, I need to use an alias with cliconfig instead of changing the registry entry.

Why is changing this registry value "unsupported" for sharepoint? After changing the entry and clearing my SPTimer cache, I can tell that it is still pointing to the old connection string. Where else is this stored?

Just asking because I would prefer not to set up a redirect rule, and continue polluting my environment with the incorrect name.

Answer (score 3):

It's unsupported because that isn't the only place the connection string resides. There are a few SharePoint Objects that would also have to be updated (including making direct changes to the Configuration database). This is unsupported in and of itself.

You'll need to use `cliconfg` to create a SQL Alias or rebuild the farm.